# Cache a complex calculation in Rails 3 model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, activerecord, model

I'm new to Ruby/Rails, so this is possibly (hopefully) a simple question that I just dont know the answer to.

I am implementing an accounting/billing system in Rails, and I'm trying to keep track of the running balance after each transaction in order to display it in the view as below:

```
Date     Description     Charges($)   Credits($)    Balance($)

Mar 2    Activity C       $4.00                       -$7.50

Feb 25   Payment for Jan                 $8.00        -$3.50

Feb 23   Activity B       $1.50                      -$11.50

Feb 20   Activity A       $2.00                      -$10.00
```

Each transaction (also known as line item) is stored in the database, with all the values above (Date, Description, Amount) except for the Balance. I can't store the balance for each transaction in the database because it may change if something happens to an earlier transaction (a payment that was posted subsequently failed later for example). So I need to calculate it on the fly for each line item, and the value for the Balance for a line item depends on the value for the line item before it (Balance = Balance of Prev Line Item + Amount for this Line Item, i.e.)

So here's my question. My current (inept) way of doing it is that in my LineItem model, I have a balance method which looks like :

```
def balance
  prev_balance = 0
  #get previous line items balance if it exists.
  last_line_item = Billing::LineItem.get_last_line_item_for_a_ledger(self.issue_date,self.ledger_item_id)

  if last_line_item
    prev_balance = last_line_item.balance
    .. some other stuff...
 end

 prev_balance + (-1*net_amount) # net_amount is the amount for the current line item
end
```

This is super costly and my view takes forever to load since I'm calculating the prev line item's balance again and again and again. Whats a better way to do this?

Comment: Could you not call balance for the first LineItem, then keep track of the current balance as you iterate over all of the items?

Comment: Is there any optimization you could do to `get_last_line_item_for_a_ledger` such as eager loading associations? Are your database fields indexed?

Comment: I have a system like yours, with transactions and balance, not for money, but for stock. I save the balance directly in the transaction. Every time a transaction is updated I update all the next transactions, so when I need to show the balance it will be already calculated. It is not a default implementation, but could help when the amount of data is big and performance is very important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're basically paying a price for not wanting to store the balance in each transaction. You could optimize your database with indices and use caches etc; but fundamentally you'll run into the problem that calculating a balance will take a long time, if you have lots of transactions.

Keep in mind that you'll continue to get new transactions, and your problem will thus get worse over time.

You could consider several design alternatives. First, like Douglas Lise mentioned, you could store the balance in each transaction. If an earlier dated transaction comes in, it means you may have to do an update of several transaction since that date. However, this has an upper-bound (depending on how "old" transactions you want to allow), so it has a reasonable worst-case behavior.

Alternatively, you can do a reconciliation step. Every month you "close the books" on transactions older than X weeks. After reconciliation you store the Balance you calculated. In `def balance` you now use your existing logic, but also refer to "balance as of the previous reconciliation". This again, provides a reasonable and predictable worst-case scenario.